# Direction of line parallel to the x-axis in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, soft-question

How can  say the direction of a line parallel to the real axis as clockwise or anti-clockwise?

[image]

More precisely what's the direction of blue line as well as orange line ?

Which one is clockwise & which one is anti-clockwise ?

**Update :** [image]

My actual question is : Suppose this is the whole contour where I want to integrate a complex function. The middle line is the negative real axis. For part $C_2$ the direction is anticlockwise (positively oriented). But for the curve $C_1$ and $C_3$ the direction is clockwise or anticlockwise so that I can use negative sign and positive sign in the evaluation of the integration on the whole contour ? How can I say that ?

Comment: What would the answer be if the lines weren't parallel?  I believe it doesn't matter.  If you view is as clockwise you get $\int_{z_{t_0}}^{x_{t_1}} f(z)dz$ and if you view it as counterclockwise you get $\int_{z_{t_1}}^{z_{t_0}} -f(z) dz$ which are both the same.  ....But it's been *decades* since I've studied this.

Comment: My book takes $C_1$ as clockwise and $C_3$ as anti-clockwise. My question is WHY?

Answer (score 0):

A line doesn't have a direction. 
It has an equation.

A vector has origin and direction.

The lines above would have equations
of the form
Im(z) = c
for some real c.

As vectors,
their specification would be
a+bt
where $t \ge 0$
and b is real.

If b > 0,
the vector goes to the right.

If b < 0,
the vector goes to the left.

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Answer (score -1):

I'd avoid using the terms "clockwise" or "anti-clockwise" since they don't apply in this context. These only refer to things moving in a circular way.

I would agree with marty cohen: we would say that these lines "go to the right/left", or "the direction of the line is to the right/left".

P.S. This question might be better off on [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/)